# Render twig templates in Symfony 2.1

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I am migrating my app to Symfony 2.1 but I'm facing a big error. I've got a command which calls the templating service to render a twig template. The code +- is:

```
 $content = $this->getContainer()->get('templating')->render('XBundle:Pdf:x.pdf.twig', array(
            'variablea' => '',
            'variableb' => ''
 ));
```

It was working without any problem in Symfony 2.0.X. But after migrating into Symfony 2.1, when that piece of code is called, an exception occurs:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Loader\TemplateLocator::isFresh() in /vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle/Factory/Resource/FileResource.php on line 49

I've reported that in symfony/asseticbundle tracker on github like 14 days ago and nobody answers, which makes me think that I am the problem here... (https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/issues/122)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: I forgot to say is that everything is properly rendered before `{{ url('my_account') }}` appears in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Did you clear the cache (`php app/console cache:clear`) and also rebuilt the bootstrap file?

Comment: Of course I did... I also reinstalled all the vendors but the problem is still happening...

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions:

- Check if you are using proper versions of the Symfony bundles. Compare the bundles versions in your composer.json file with versions in the default Symfony 2.1 distribution:  https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v2.1.2/composer.json
- Make sure your Symfony 2.1 installation is not still using Symfony 2.0 cache files. If you are not sure about this delete the cache folder content. In your project root directory do `rm -rf app/cache/*` and set up appropiate permissions as explained in the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup